# how to print every second line using sed after a specific line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed

I have a big text file URL.txt. I want to print every second line on the terminal (without altering the content of the file) after line number 40 using *sed* command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed you can do

```
sed -n '40~2 p' file
```

Comment: I think this is correct however the question says "after line number 40" so strictly speaking it should be `sed '42~2p;d' file`